# Python Paramiko hangs at .recv(1024)

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I'm having issues with using the invoke shell receiving output from a particular command. The purpose of the script is to log in and check the status of a particular application on linux/unix servers. The problem stems, the list of servers are huge and *not all servers have this application*. So The script works on the servers that has the application and even pulls the data and prints it to the screen, however when the scrip encounters "-bash: CMD: command not found" it hangs and doesn't iterate through the list.

I also confirmed using wireshark and filtering for the IP of the server ip.addr == x.x.x.x the TCP connection is established therefore ruling out any ACL, FW, and or IP tables along the path. I can't further elaborate on the packet within wireshark as it's encrypted.

I can see the the server communicate with my desktop(client) and sends multiple encrypted packets of multiple lens. The script seems to hang right before the print statement (stuck).

Now granted the most ideal circumstance is to use exec shell, but I want to design this script to be scale-able in the future.

I've used this script before on network appliances and even on serves, the script works when the expected response in uniform meaning, show route, uname -a, those are all expected outcomes, but I think there is something in different to the bash no command error which is causing the issue the receive.

```
# ***** Open Plain Text
f = open("nfsus.txt")

# ***** Read & Store into Variable
hn=(f.read().splitlines())
f.close()

# ***** Credentials 
#username =  raw_input("Please Enter Username: ")
#password =  getpass.getpass("Please Enter Passwod: ")


# ***** SSH
client=paramiko.SSHClient()

def connect_ssh(hn):
    try:
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(hn, 22, username, password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

        print 'Connection Attempting to: '+(hn)
        channel = client.get_transport().open_session()
        channel.invoke_shell()



        channel.sendall("CMD \n")
        cmd = channel.recv(1024)

        #SCRIPT HANGS HERE! ^
        print ('stuck')

        #print (cmd)

    except Exception, e:
        print '*** Caught exception: %s: %s' % (e.__class__, e)
    try:
        channel.close()
    except:
        pass

# *****Create Loop through input.txt (contains a list of IP address)
for x in hn:
    connect_ssh(x)
```

I'm new to Python and admit, I suck hard! However, I'm really trying my hardest to understand every detail of scripting. I never wrote anything ever in my life, in python or any other language. I'm excited to learn, but please have patience because I suck! I went through the paramiko documentation, but somethings I haven't yet fully understand and I'm hoping someone here would be cool enough to show this noob the error of my ways.

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at Paramiko in a dogs age, but in this case bash (the shell) is sending the error message on "STDERR", not "STDOUT". It may be Paramiko isn't listening to STEDRR, so it's not getting the error messages, or it's trapping them some other way.

```
ortep@Motte ~
$ foobar
-bash: foobar: command not found

ortep@Motte ~
$ foobar 2>/dev/null
ortep@Motte ~
$
```

In the second calling of "foobar" I redirected (>) STDERR (2) to the /dev/null device.

You can also redirect it to "STDOUT" thusly:

```
ortep@Motte ~
$ foobar 2>&1
-bash: foobar: command not found
```

This looks the same because on the ssh console STDOUT and STDERR are (kinda) the same thing.

So that gives you two options that might help. One is to do:

```
channel.sendall("CMD 2>&1 \n")
```

The other is to check for the existence of the command:

```
channel.sendall("if [[-x /path/to/CMD ]]; then /path/to/CMD/; else echo "CMD not found"; fi \n)
```

The first one is easier to try, the second one you can expand on the "else" section to give you more information (like "; else echo "CMD not on $(hostname)". Which may or may not be useful).

Comment: Dude!!! You're a Genius!! I would never be able to figure this out! Please sir how do you even know that!!!!???!!! I'm baffled at this for days, invoke shell i didn't know I could redirect a command to an error in bash/

Comment: I've been using Unix and Linux personally and professionally since January of 1993, and using Python since 1995. Eventually even I learn things.